# Problems with _csv.Error: sequence expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I have a list of python dictionaries that I'm trying to write the values into csv file, but for some reason I keep getting **_csv.Error: sequence expected**

Here is the sample code:

```
import csv
import os, sys

headers = ['id', 'Info']
data = [{'id': 1, 'Info': 'Example 1'}, {'id': 2, 'Info':'Example 2'}]

with open('all_csv.csv', 'wt') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
   writer.writerow(headers)
   for each in data:
      writer.writerow(each.values())
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in python 3, `values()` doesn't return a `list` anymore. You have to convert it first:

```
writer.writerow(list(each.values()))
```

note that dictionaries aren't ordered, so the order of the columns isn't defined (unless you're using Python 3.6 or higher), so maybe you want to use a `csv.DictWriter` object instead to avoid that your header doesn't match your rows.

Here's how I'd do it using `csv.DictWriter`:

```
import csv

data = [{'id': 1, 'Info': 'Example 1'}, {'id': 2, 'Info':'Example 2'}]

with open('all_csv.csv', 'w', newline="") as f:
   writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames = data[0], delimiter=',')
   writer.writeheader()
   writer.writerows(data)
```

the output is:

```
Info,id
Example 1,1
Example 2,2
```

Comment: Thanks for your amazing help. The header is in 9 columns, is there a way of simply defining the headers in a list? I noticed that my output has now jumbled up :(

Comment: passing `headers` as fieldnames should be ok too. But the fieldnames must match the keys exactly.

Comment: You are a life saver :)